Apparent Code Injection Attempt
I am new to this database (and to CiviCRM generally) but I am finding that it contains a lot of dud records over the last several months which appear to be code injection attempts. It's running on WordPress.
For example, a display name of "fnfOzvSR LoTTaXiD' OR 493=(SELECT 493 FROM PG_SLEEP(15))—"
I hope that these attempts will have been unsuccessful, but is there a way of tracing how they were generated? The activities they have seem to relate to forms which are not publicly visible.

The most reliable would be to get a timestamp of one of those records, then look in your web server logs for which URL was accessed at that time (within one second or so).  It should be a POST request, which should narrow things down if your site gets a lot of traffic.
Under normal circumstances, you'll see the page get loaded first with a GET request by the same IP address, and then you can visit that page as an anonymous user, which should make clearer what happened.  However, with a bot, it's possible that someone just recorded the URL for POST requests.  It should still hopefully be obvious which URL was used.
You should also go to Administer » System Settings » Misc and make sure Accept profile submissions from external sites is set to No.

Thank you; this is slightly beyond me at the moment, but it points me in the right direction.
